# Lego EV3 simulator and programming

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, robotc, fll

I've been searching and testing for hours. There is little information on this subject though. I have some specific requirements for a Lego EV3 simulator and programming environment.

- I do not want to continue to use Lego EV3 programming blocks.
- I would like to use a robust, alternative graphical programming language such as Scratch, Modkit, or MakeCode.
- The simulator needs to have access to current FLL game fields.
- The programming environment and code needs to be portable to a physical robot.

I am aware of Robot Virtual Worlds and Virtual Robot Toolkit. Both are of interest to me and I am familiar with both to some degree. However, the programming aspect has been a challenge.

Virtual Robot Toolkit makes the EV3 connects to the programming platform over a virtual wifi connection. That's great if I want to use Lego EV3 programming, but I don't. So, is there another programming language that has a "bridge" to connect and program an EV3 running standard EV3 firmware over wifi? Specifically that works with VRT?

Robot Virtual Worlds has support for Robot C Graphical which is a potential choice. However, Robot C Graphical is really buggy and limited (no support for functions at all). In addition, I think the Robot C environment requires downloading a different firmware to the brick which is a drawback and eliminates it's ability to be used in VRT. I also don't know if they have any current FLL fields available in RVW.

So, does anyone know of a way to bridge one of these two virtualization platforms with a good graphical programming language while having current FLL fields available?

Comment: I don't know if this will work or not, but EV3Basic compiles to the same byte codes as the official EV3 software from LEGO, so it may be possible to use it with Robot Virtual Worlds, assuming that it uses the compiled .rbf file. https://github.com/c0pperdragon/EV3Basic

Comment: @DavidLechner This looks hopeful. I'm not opposed to teaching a simple to learn BASIC to students. It's where I started at 8 yrs old. I researched it briefly and it says it connects over bluetooth and wifi to the brick - so technically it should support virtual robotics toolkit which shows up as a wifi brick. Thanks for the tip!